# Socket does not receive data. (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

My Android program's MainActivity spawns another activity, called SecondActivity, which in turn creates another activity, called TempActivity.

SecondActivity creates a socket and establishes connection with a server. It then equates that socket to a static socket object of a class called SocketHandler (so that other threads can write/read data on that socket).

When started, TempActivity is supposed to send a message("get temp") to the server to prompt it to start sending temperature readings at 5 second intervals, which will then be displayed in a text box on the Android device.

My issue is that, when I start my app and start TempActivity once, the readings are displayed fine. But when I press back and start TempActivity again I no longer receive any readings. I have no idea what's causing this issue.

SecondActivity looks like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.152");
            sockfd = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
            SocketHandler.setSocket(sockfd);
            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sockfd.getOutputStream())),true);
            try {
                input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockfd.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        } 

        catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My TempActivity looks like this:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);

    sockfd2 = SocketHandler.getSocket();
    temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempreading);

    //Output stream
    try{
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sockfd2.getOutputStream())),true);
    out.println("get temp");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }

    //InputStream
    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sockfd2.getInputStream()));
         new Thread(new TempRecv()).start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  class TempRecv implements Runnable {
       @Override
       public void run() {  
        while(true)
        {
         try{
           reading=input.readLine();
           runOnUiThread(showmessage);
           }
           catch(IOException e)
           {
           }
        }
       }

    }

   Runnable showmessage = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                   temp.setText(reading);
            }
        };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        out.println("stop temp");
        this.finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please **do not store data in an Activity**. If the user turns the screen, your Activity will be removed from the screen and re-created. (You can lock screen in one orientation, but this will not stop Android from trying to re-create your Activity, it will just make it more difficult to reproduce this behavior).

From the *MVC* (*Model-View-Controller*) viewpoint, an Activity is a *Controller*, the *View* is what you get with the layout XML (sometimes people define custom *View* classes like `TextViewWithImages`, but for the most part the existing classes are reused).

And *Model* is what must survive a screen turn. I would use a singleton for that.

I have to note that sometimes (on low memory) Android can kill a process and re-create it later, thus re-setting all static variables. This is why bundles are used by Activities to pass data to themselves in the future. All this sounds schizophrenic (indeed, you cannot just store the application state in variables, you have to save and restore everything, converting between at least two formats), but processes are not killed often, so I would start with a singleton containing application data.

Later you may add saving/restoring application data and/or implement a Service (it sounds like data get downloaded in background anyway).

You do not need a Service to have your background worker thread running, but you do need a *Model* singleton to use the data retrieved by that thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a BufferedWriter, therefore you are writing the "get temp" command into the buffer but the buffer is never transferred as this only happens if the buffer is full or you flush it.

Therefore the simple solution is to eliminate the `BufferedWriter` as you want unbuffered communication:

```
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sockfd2.getOutputStream()),true);
```

An alternative would be to flush the out writer:

```
out.flush();
```